# Is this acceptable practice initialize array on the heap?

Tags: ios

Is this acceptable code?:

```
unsigned char *buffer= malloc(16 * sizeof(*buffer));
        if (buffer == NULL) {
            errorText.text= @"Insufficient memory.";
            NSLog(@"%@",@"Insufficient memory.");
            return;
        }
        unsigned char temp[16]= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};
        memcpy(buffer,temp,16);
        NSData* seed= [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:16];
```

or:

```
unsigned char *buffer= malloc(16 * sizeof(*buffer));
if (buffer == NULL) {
    errorText.text= @"Insufficient memory.";
    NSLog(@"%@",@"Insufficient memory.");
    return;
}
memset(buffer,0,16); // set all bytes to zero
buffer[0]= 0x01;
buffer[1]= 0x02;
buffer[2]= 0x03;
buffer[3]= 0x04;
buffer[4]= 0x05;
buffer[5]= 0x06;
buffer[6]= 0x07;
buffer[7]= 0x08;
buffer[8]= 0x09;
buffer[9]= 0x0a;
buffer[10]= 0x0b;
buffer[11]= 0x0c;
buffer[12]= 0x0d;
buffer[13]= 0x0e;
buffer[14]= 0x0f;
buffer[15]= 0x10;
NSData* seed= [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:16];
```

My C is a bit rusty!

Comment: Instead of using `memset`, why not just use `calloc`?

Comment: @Jacob... The call to memset is optional, so I coded it separate so that I could comment it out later. Do you think the temporary array on the stack is reasonable? It just is easier to code the actual seed using the initializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ edited to remove bogus advice about not using malloc with dataWithBytesNoCopy]

Another option would be to just use `-dataWithBytes:` and let NSData take care of the copying for you:

```
    static unsigned char seedBytes[16]= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};
    NSData* seed= [NSData dataWithBytes:seedBytes length:16];
```

Comment: Hi @David Gelhar... Good points and I am open to understanding. I called malloc since the examples on line call malloc and the docs say: "A buffer containing data for the new object. bytes must point to a memory block allocated with malloc." Also the default appears to be freeWhenDone:YES as "If YES, the returned object takes ownership of the bytes pointer and frees it on deallocation." So my murky understanding is that I call malloc and NSData calls free. This seems similar to calling CopyTo on a CComBSTR that I pass from a DLL.

Comment: Good point about the fact that `-dataWithBytesNoCopy:` frees its argument; I missed that (don't tend to use that API much). I'll update the answer...

Comment: Now I don't know how I missed dataWithBytes! Thank you. I figured there had to be an easier way to do this.